# Create alias URLs including a path to redirect or forward to other websites

Tags: redirects, apache

To unify the complex URLs of different social media profiles I want to create forwardings/redirects from my own domain to the domain of the respective profile. For these alias domains I want to use a path structure instead of normal subdomains.

An example: Requests to subdomain.mywebsite.com/facebook should be forwarded to facebook.com/my.name.randomnumberblablabla.

For DNS redirections of course no paths can be specified, how do I configure redirections of URLs that contain paths? My domain is hosted at greenhost.nl and an Apache2 is used as webserver.

Comment: To clarify, by "forwardings/redirects" (and the `reverse-proxy` tag), are you wanting to mask/hide the real `facebook.com` URL from the user? Or do you want a simple redirect?

Comment: @MrWhite I only want to set up simple redirects to build a uniform, easy to remember link structure for complex URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like i could answer my question by myself. When the apache2 module mod_alias is enabled, adding these lines in /etc/apache2/virtualconf.conf does the job:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mywebsite.com
    Redirect permanent /facebook https://facebook.com/my.name.randomnumberblablabla
</VirtualHost>
```